# mysql recovery process cannot proceed

Tags: mysql

I tried to restart mysql database. The database is around 400 GB.

The recovery process always gets stuck when it comes to

> Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1102472406659.

Please click links below to get details:

[image]

[image]

My question is:

is it because I have a large database so it takes long? If it is the case, how I estimate how long it will take?
Can I skip the "doing recovery" process to restart the database?

I have tried `innodb_force_recovery = 5` but it is still the same.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm assuming `1102472406659` is your last entry in the binary log and after that it starts writing to the database. Depending on how many tables/rows there are and what your hardware setup looks like, writing 400GB can take a long time. I wouldn't be suprised that if there are many rows and the hardware is average, this process could take up to 24-48 hours. Try running `mysql -e 'show full processlist'` in a seperate console to see if it's running any queries.

Comment: The binary log isn't used for InnoDB recovery. Besides, until crash recovery finishes the server doesn't accept incoming connections.

Comment: @Oldskool thank you Oldskool. It is exactly what you said and the db recovered now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB crash recovery process takes more time if redo log larger. You should wait till finishes, starting MySQL with `innodb_force_recovery` may  damage the database, don't do it (I guess it's too late for this advice) unless the crash recovery fails.

To speed up crash recovery you can bump InnoDB buffer pool size as much as you can.